# PostGIS, Postgres,geocoding...

Tags: postgresql, geocoding, postgis

I want to be able to do the following:

Select a Polygon and a point and see if the point lies within the polygon...I thought I could do this with MySQL but after a whole day of research it is simply not possible.

I have seen I need to use postgres and postgis, I have never used postgres before.

I have managed to install postgres and postpgadmin and it looks like I have created a database and got it up and running. Now I apparently need to add postgis to the database in order to use the functions? arent they just part of the postgres library? and why are people saying I need to add tables to the database to use the functions?

How do I add postgis to my database?

Can anyone give me any simple clear examples of a query to see if a point is in a polygon?

Comment: Start by reading the manual http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ch02.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For purely geometrical queries you won't need postgis. Postgis is required when you want to mess with geographical data.

For an example of checking if a point is inside a polygon, this query should make it clear to you:

```
postgres=# select '((0,0), (1,1), (1,0))'::polygon @> '(.5, .5)'::point;
```

This will print true, meaning that the triangle formed by the points (0,0), (1,1) and (1,0) contains the point (.5, .5).

For more info check: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/datatype-geometric.html and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/functions-geometry.html

Comment: Thank You!!! it works, I got so confused reading around everyone said to use postgis. Is there a mysql version of this? he says hopefully :)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't played with MySQL for a long time now, and thus I do not know how much support for geometric types and functions they have. Please also note that although there is support in postgres for geometric types and operations, postgis probably facilitates some jobs a lot.

Answer (score 0):

PostGIS is the spatial extension for the PostgreSQL database, and as is the case with many general-purpose databases, spatial functions have to be installed on top of a regular install.

The PostGIS website is informative, with nice [documentation](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/) so head over there and read everything you need to know about obtaining and installing PostGIS.

Once installed and tested you'll need to [spatially enable](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-1.5/ch02.html#id2619431) your database and then you're all set.  If you have a dataset, of course.